# Partial Derivative Becomes a Total

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider a function $f(x_1,x_2, t)$, and suppose that we have $x_1 = x_1(u_1,u_2,t)$, $x_2=x_2(u_1,u_2,t)$. From here define a new function:

$$ \bar{f}(u_1,u_2,t) = f(x_1(u_1,u_2,t), x_2(u_1,u_2,t),t)$$

I am doing a calculation where I need to take the partial derivative of $\bar{f}$ with respect to $t$.

At first sight, I thought that:

$$ \frac{\partial\bar{f}} {\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x_1,x_2,t)\Big\vert_{x_i = x_i(u_1,u_2)}$$

To get my calculation right however, the answer should be:

$$\frac{\partial\bar{f}} {\partial t}(u_1,u_2,u_3,t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x_1,x_2,t)\Big\vert_{x_i = x_i(u_1,u_2,u_3)} + \nabla f\Big\vert_{x_i = x_i(u_1,u_2,u_3)} \cdot \vec{v}  $$
where:
$$ \vec{v} = \vec{v}(u_1,u_2,t) = \sum \frac{ \partial x_i(u_1,u_2,t)}{\partial t } \textbf{e}_i$$

The right hand side of the previous equation reminds me of the total derivative, so the actual answer is:

$$
\frac{ \partial \bar{f} } {\partial t} = \frac{ df} { dt} (x_1(u_1,u_2,t), x_2(u_1,u_2,t),t)
$$

which has me confused because, how come the partial becomes a total? I hope someone could clear this confusion for me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use the chain rule: $\frac{\partial\bar{f}} {\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x_1,x_2,t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\frac{x_1}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\frac{x_2}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} $.